# Is there a way to find out how many instances of the root user are logged into a Linux machine?

Tags: ssh, users, root, vmware

We have a handful of users that login to our Linux virtual machine as `root` either through the vSphere client or through SSH and I want to see if there is a way to tell if multiple `root` users are logged in at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `who` command to find out all the logged in users. There is `w` command also available to find out the same.

Comment: I don't think "who" or "w" will show multiple root users logged in. You can also use "users"

Comment: Try it for yourself. `w` and `who` both show one line per root session and the hostname/ip that they are logged in from.

Comment: Note: that in many cases remote rsh and remote xterm users will not appear in who, w .... so you can't fully depend on this.

Comment: But shouldn't they be visible in any case in `last | head x` which reads from wtmp? You could use `last | head -n 100 | grep root | grep "still logged in"` though that might also return roots that have already logged out some minutes ago.

Comment: Ok I tested this with a coworker and "w" "who" and "users" all show multiple root accounts. Thanks!